# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/app/code/Ves/Megamenu/Model/Config/Source/StoreCategories.php on line 284

Tags: magento2, php, module, megamenu

I have this error when I add special characters to menu or categories like "&"
It's from module Ves Megamenu.

> Warning:
>   Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in /var/www/html/app/code/Ves/Megamenu/Model/Config/Source/StoreCategories.php on line 284

Warning Line:

```
$categoriesTrees = $this->getCategoriesTree();
foreach ($categoriesTrees as $category) {
    $this->generatCategory($category);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions was to change this line to:

```
$categoriesTrees = $this->getCategoriesTree();
if(is_array($categoriesTrees)){
   foreach ($categoriesTrees as $category) {
       $this->generatCategory($category);
   }
}
```

Now I can use "&" or "/" in categories names, without crashing the site.

Useful source:
https://thisinterestsme.com/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach/

Comment: Good solution solved the issue for me as well +1 for that.